# How to create a custom implementation of ToListAsync()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, overriding

I am trying to create a custom implementation of List where my list IntegrityList enforces some business rules.

```
[Serializable]
public class IntegrityList<TSource> : List<TSource> where TSource : IEvent
{
... business logic...
}
```

But I also need to have some custom extension methods like LINQ's  ToList() and EF's ToListAsync(). I looked into the implementation of Microsoft and created a simple ToIntegrityList() extension method, but I cannot find the implementation of ToListAsync(). Does anyone have any idea how to implement such method?

```
public static class IntegrityListExtensions
{
    public static IntegrityList<TSource> ToIntegrityList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) where TSource : IEvent
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        return new IntegrityList<TSource>(source);
    }

    public static Task<IntegrityList<TSource>> ToIntegrityListAsync<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source) where TSource : IEvent
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        throw new NotImplementedException("Missing implementation");
    }

    public static Task<IntegrityList<TSource>> ToIntegrityListAsync<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where TSource : IEvent
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        else if (cancellationToken == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cancellationToken));
        throw new NotImplementedException("Missing implementation");
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you're referring to `ToListAsync()` in the context of Entity Framework. I would consider reviewing your design, e.g. inheritance vs composition

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the use case of your `IntegrityList` (*1), any case, here the static extensions methods:

```cs
public static class IntegrityListExtensions
{
    public static IntegrityList<TSource> ToIntegrityList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) where TSource : IEvent
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        var myList = new IntegrityList<TSource>();
        myList.AddRange(source);
        return myList;
    }

    public static Task<IntegrityList<TSource>> ToIntegrityListAsync<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source) where TSource : IEvent
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        var myList = source.ToIntegrityList();
        return Task.FromResult(myList);
    }

    public static Task<IntegrityList<TSource>> ToIntegrityListAsync<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where TSource : IEvent
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        var myList = source.ToIntegrityList();
        return Task.FromResult(myList);
    }
}
```

(*1) May be you are looking for `public class IntegrityList<TSource> : IList<TSource>, IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> where TSource : IEvent`. Notice the `IList` instead `List` and also the `IAsyncEnumerable` interface to deal with async.

Comment: IntegrityList enforces that the new entry in the list has the same AggregateId as the first entry in the list if that is not the case an error should be shown. I ment to use List<T> as I am just reusing the the original List implementation but my IntegrityCheck is ran before any insert/add/update methods :-). Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: Andrea, because of this, you should to implement `IList` instead to inherit from `List`.  Because `public void Add(T item);` is not virtual, and you can't override the add behavior. Also, has no sense to have a sync list and convert it to async. If you have the control of async though `IAsyncEnumerable`you can transform your list in a really async List.

Comment: You can override it using the new keyword (not sure if override is the correct term when using the new keyword) `public new void Add(TSource value) { IntegrityCheck(value); base.Add(value); }`. I will take a look into the benifits of using the interface instead of inheritance :-)

Answer (score 0):

- Implementation in EF Core [EF Core GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs)

More resources

- [Iterating with Async Enumerables in C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8)
- [async-streams (C# 8.0)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/async-streams.md)

A basic iteration might look like this, you can extend it to save results to the list and do whatever you want in between

```
await foreach (int item in RangeAsync(10, 3).WithCancellation(token))
  Console.Write(item + " "); // Prints 10 11 12
```